# Set the Crawler rules dynamically in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am setting up a crawler using Scrapy and want to be able to setup the rule dynamically based on a variable in the spider. The code I have is something like this:

```
class MainSpider(CrawlSpider):
  def __init__(self, configuration):
    super(MainSpider, self).__init__(configuration.name)
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    self.product_link_id = configuration.product_link_id

  rules = (
    # call parse_link on all links from starting url
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=product_link_id), callback='parse_link', follow=False),)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the instance variable there, which doesn't work. I am fairly certain this is because of a fundamental Python issue with my code that has nothing to do with Scrapy but not sure what it is as I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to define the variable at the top of the class (outside the constructor) so it could be picked up by rules. Something like:

```
class MainSpider(CrawlSpider):
   product_link_id = None
   def __init__(self, configuration):
   ....
   rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=product_link_id), callback='parse_link', follow=False),)
```